# Instagram crashes when my android app trying post on it using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, instagram, appcelerator

I am developing an app for Android which should  share image  to the Instagram app. The app opens up the camera, takes a picture and then the Instagram app is opened with the "Crop photo" window active. It seems to be loading the picture, but after a couple of seconds the app crashes, i can't see that the image ever gets loaded.

Don't understand where i am going wrong.

Thanks..!!!

```
 var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action: Ti.Android.ACTION_SEND,
    packageName:"com.instagram.android",
    type: "image/*"
});

intent.putExtraUri(intent.EXTRA_STREAM,MediaPath);
intent.putExtra(Ti.Android.EXTRA_TEXT, "Posting via My Andorid App... Testing");
intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP;
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: that is Instagram problem dude not your's

Comment: May be, But when I am open Instagram App directly it works, but when i am trying to upload from my App it crashes..

Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: [How do I report a technical problem in the instagram app](https://help.instagram.com/381579045265733)

Comment: Thanks, I have reported problem to Instagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should use this code that i already implemented in my code:

```
String type = "image/*";
String filename = "/myPhoto.jpg";
String mediaPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + filename;
```

and call a method to open Instagram.

```
createInstagramIntent(type, mediaPath);
```

and method body like:

```
private void createInstagramIntent(String type, String mediaPath){

// Create the new Intent using the 'Send' action.
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

// Set the MIME type
share.setType(type);

// Create the URI from the media
File media = new File(mediaPath);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media);

// Add the URI to the Intent.
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

// Broadcast the Intent.
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));
}
```

and dear for more information you can see Instagram official site to share image and video [here](https://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/?hl=en).
enjoy your code:)

Comment: Thanks Piyush, but using my code I am able to open Instagram but it crashes after couple of second I am not able to see image over there.. :(

Comment: so,dear this is not your code problem.its instagram problem.and please report to them.

Comment: There is no any problem for Instagram, Actually I made silly mistake that passing wrong image path. Also instead  intent.putExtraUri(intent.EXTRA_STREAM,MediaPath);  I Put  intent.putExtraUri(intent.EXTRA_STREAM,""+MediaPath);
And it Works...!!! both of above code is fine :)